# Drawing contour around the modular fundamental domain

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I am just a beginner with TikZ and I am willing to draw in Latex the following contour, found in Serre's book :

[image: Contour of the modular fundamental domain]

Any help or references to draw this kind of contour efficiently (if it exists) is welcome !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better, at least to put some code with some basic things in the manual to escape the situation do it for me, but as it is a trivial code that you could put at the end or a fairly competent one, my habit is to rewrite it my way since this situation allows it, that way a solution using `intersections`, `calc`, and `decorations.markings`, there are things to improve but there you have a code to try to understand how...

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\scriptsize\bf\sffamily,
        scale=2,
        line width=0.75pt,
        MyArrow/.style={
            draw,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position #1 with {
                        \fill(0:3pt) -- (90+50:3pt) -- (180:1pt) -- (270-50:3pt) ;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        Mydashed/.style={
            dash pattern =on 3pt off 2pt on 3pt off 2pt,
        }
    ]
    %Defining coodinates
    \coordinate(E) at (0.5,3); \node[anchor=south west] at (E) {E};
    \coordinate(A) at (-0.5,3); \node[anchor=south east] at (A) {A};
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (O') at (90:1);

    %Draw the X axis
    \fill
        (O) circle (0.7pt) node[anchor=north]{0}
        (O') circle (0.7pt)
        (O)edge ++(1.2,0) edge++(-1.2,0);

    %Definig paths
    \path[name path=hemicircle]
        (0:1)node[anchor=north]{1}
            arc (0:180:1)node[anchor=north]{-1};
    \path[name path=CircleC]
        (O') circle (3pt);
    \path[name path=rectangleAE]
        (A) rectangle (E |- O);
    %Find firts intersections for centers of circles for B,B',D'D' points
    \path[name intersections={of=hemicircle and rectangleAE}]
        (intersection-1) coordinate (CenterCircleD) 
        (intersection-2) coordinate (CenterCircleB);
    %Defining paths for circles B and D
    \path[name path=CircleB] 
        (CenterCircleB) circle (5pt);
    \path[name path=CircleD] 
        (CenterCircleD) circle (5pt);

    %Find coordinates   
    \path[name intersections={of=hemicircle and CircleC}]
        (intersection-1) coordinate (C')
        (intersection-2) coordinate (C);
    \node[anchor=north] at (C') {C'};
    \node[anchor=north] at (C) {C};

    \path[name intersections={of=hemicircle and CircleB}]
        (intersection-1) coordinate (B')
        (intersection-2) coordinate (B'2);
        \node[anchor=north] at (B') {B'};
    \path[name intersections={of=rectangleAE and CircleB}]
        (intersection-1) coordinate (B)
        (intersection-2) coordinate (B2);
        \node[anchor=east] at (B) {B};

    \path[name intersections={of=hemicircle and CircleD}]
        (intersection-1) coordinate (D)
        (intersection-2) coordinate (D2);
        \node[anchor=north] at (D) {D};     
    \path[name intersections={of=rectangleAE and CircleD}]
        (intersection-1) coordinate (D')
        (intersection-2) coordinate (D'2);
        \node[anchor=west] at (D') {D'};

    \def\DrawArc[#1](#2)(#3)(#4)#5{%1:style 2: center 3: start 4: end 5: change direction if \n3>\n2 %Needs conditional improvement
        \draw[#1]
        let \p1 = ($(#3)-(#2)$), \p2 = ($(#4)-(#2)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
            \n2 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)},
            \n3 = {atan2(\y2,\x2)}
        in
            (#2)++(\n2:\n1) arc (\n2:\n3-#5:\n1);
    }

    %Drawing the contour
    \draw[MyArrow=0.5] (A) -- (B);
    \DrawArc[MyArrow=0.5](CenterCircleB)(B)(B'){0}
    \DrawArc[MyArrow=0.5](O)(B')(C){0}
    \DrawArc[MyArrow=0.5](O')(C)(C'){360}
    \DrawArc[MyArrow=0.5](O)(C')(D){0}
    \DrawArc[MyArrow=0.5](CenterCircleD)(D)(D'){0}  
    \draw[MyArrow=0.5] (D') -- (E);
    \draw[MyArrow=0.5] (E) -- (A);

    %Drawing other details

    \DrawArc[thick](O)(180:1)(CenterCircleB){0}
    \DrawArc[thick](O)(CenterCircleD)(0:1){0}
    \DrawArc[Mydashed](O)(CenterCircleB)(B'){0}
    \DrawArc[Mydashed](O)(D)(CenterCircleD){0}

    \draw[Mydashed] (B) -- (B |- O)node[anchor=north]{-1/2};
    \draw[Mydashed] (D') -- (D' |- O)node[anchor=north]{1/2};

    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```